# How would I refactor these unit system methods that return an enum from a string?

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, refactoring

I have the following three methods:

```
    private static Temperature.TemperatureScale GetTemperatureEnumFromString(string enumString)
    {
        return (Temperature.TemperatureScale)
            Enum.Parse(typeof (Temperature.TemperatureScale), enumString);
    }

    private static Stress.StressScale GetStressEnumFromString(string enumString)
    {
        return (Stress.StressScale)
            Enum.Parse(typeof (Stress.StressScale), enumString);
    }

    private static VolumetricFlow.VolumetricFlowScale GetVolumetricFlowEnumFromString(string enumString)
    {
        return
            (VolumetricFlow.VolumetricFlowScale) 
                Enum.Parse(typeof (VolumetricFlow.VolumetricFlowScale), 
                           enumString);
    }
```

I'm trying to understand C# concepts like the dynamic keyword and generic type casting.  I would really like to refactor these three methods into one, because otherwise I will have to utilize about 5 more methods yet to be written for other unit system scales.  Does anyone have a good way to refactor these methods into one?  If so, can you also explain how it works?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string enumString)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T),enumString);
}
```

---

```
var val = GetValue<Stress.StressScale>("...");
```

Comment: Awesome, seems to be working!  Thanks!  Anything I need to be careful with while using this generic type?